# HikariCP Main - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@22af43cf marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorC ode(17002)

Tags: artifactory, hikaricp

UPDATE:
I've upgraded application to Pro. Some time issue was not appearing what give me hope that somehow issue got fixed. And one week ago issue came back.

During issue being reported by Artofactory I did checked that Netcat is connecting DB-IP:port, same goes for sqlplus. That lead me to idea that DB, Network wise, all seems to be good.

artifactory system.yaml:

```
   shared:
        env:
            LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/instantclient_18_5
        database:
        type: oracle
            driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<>
    
            username: <Artifactory_DB_user>
            password: <Artifactory_DB_pass>
    
        extraJavaOpts: "-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
        script:
        serviceStartTimeout: 120
    artifactory:
        port: 8081
        tomcat:
        connector:
                maxThreads: 200
                sendReasonPhrase: true
                relaxedPathChars: '[]'
                relaxedQueryChars: '[]'
        user: artifactory
        database:
        ## Max connections to keep idle
            maxIdleConnections: 10
            ## Min connections to keep idle
            minIdleConnections: 1
            ## Max connections to the database the main connection pool can consume
            maxOpenConnections: 40
    access:
        http:
        port: 8040
        tomcat:
        connector:
                maxThreads: 50
                sendReasonPhrase: true
    frontend:
        logging:
        application:
                ## The log level: error, warning, info, debug, trace
                level: error
    metadata:
        logging:
        application:
                ## The log level: error, warn, info, debug, trace
                level: error
    event:
        logging:
        application:
            ## The log level: error, warn, info, debug, trace
            ## This value is configurable during runtime
                level: error
```

---

**Original post:**

I've got Artifactory OSS instance which is used few times a day. Mostly by automation tool. Looking into logs of it I've found that there is reoccurring error.

I've tested that ojdbc connection is working. I did that following that [post](https://dba010.com/2019/09/30/simpe-java-code-to-test-connection-to-oracle-database/)

All 3 error steps are always same. Application will run before and after. All deployments are done but seeing error in logs wonders me. From DB side nothing specal is being reported. Also is not helpful to scale instance up.

```
2021-06-18T07:59:28.065Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [2067b8e822444df7] [c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection:182   ] [art-exec-4          ] - HikariCP Main - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@22af43cf marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:1043)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2052)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2057)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:387)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
       at org.jfrog.storage.wrapper.JFrogConnectionWrapper.invoke(JFrogConnectionWrapper.java:106)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.commit(Unknown Source)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:329)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.updateArtifactoryServerHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.updateArtifactoryServerHeartbeat(ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.java:180)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.updateHeartbeat(ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.java:130)
       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor211.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy286.updateHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl$HeartbeatJob.onExecute(ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.java:214)
       at org.artifactory.schedule.QuartzCommand.doExecute(QuartzCommand.java:76)
       at org.artifactory.schedule.QuartzCommand.execute(QuartzCommand.java:57)
       at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
       at org.artifactory.opentracing.TraceableRunnableDecorator.run(TraceableRunnableDecorator.java:31)
       at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:53)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler$IOReadTimeoutException: Socket read timed out
       at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:258)
       at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:184)
       at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:544)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:234)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:174)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:122)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:100)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:86)
       at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:762)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:427)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:394)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:72)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:991)
       ... 35 common frames omitted
2021-06-18T07:59:28.067Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [2067b8e822444df7] [s.d.s.DbTransactionManager:902] [art-exec-4          ] - Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.commit(Unknown Source)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCommit(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:329)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.updateArtifactoryServerHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.updateArtifactoryServerHeartbeat(ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.java:180)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.updateHeartbeat(ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.java:130)
       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor211.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy286.updateHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl$HeartbeatJob.onExecute(ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.java:214)
       at org.artifactory.schedule.QuartzCommand.doExecute(QuartzCommand.java:76)
       at org.artifactory.schedule.QuartzCommand.execute(QuartzCommand.java:57)
       at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
       at org.artifactory.opentracing.TraceableRunnableDecorator.run(TraceableRunnableDecorator.java:31)
       at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:53)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
       at org.jfrog.storage.wrapper.JFrogConnectionWrapper.invoke(JFrogConnectionWrapper.java:106)
       ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:1043)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2052)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:2057)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.commit(ProxyConnection.java:387)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.commit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
       ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.net.nt.TimeoutInterruptHandler$IOReadTimeoutException: Socket read timed out
       at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:258)
       at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:184)
       at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:544)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:234)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:174)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:122)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:100)
       at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:86)
       at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:762)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:427)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:394)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:72)
       at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:991)
       ... 35 common frames omitted
2021-06-18T07:59:28.068Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [2067b8e822444df7] [actoryHeartbeatServiceImpl:133] [art-exec-4          ] - Failed to update heartbeat for [srvartfactory]
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.rollback(Unknown Source)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:344)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:892)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:775)
       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386)
       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172.updateArtifactoryServerHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
       at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.updateArtifactoryServerHeartbeat(ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.java:180)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.updateHeartbeat(ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.java:130)
       at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor211.invoke(Unknown Source)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy286.updateHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
       at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl$HeartbeatJob.onExecute(ArtifactoryHeartbeatServiceImpl.java:214)
       at org.artifactory.schedule.QuartzCommand.doExecute(QuartzCommand.java:76)
       at org.artifactory.schedule.QuartzCommand.execute(QuartzCommand.java:57)
       at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
       at org.artifactory.opentracing.TraceableRunnableDecorator.run(TraceableRunnableDecorator.java:31)
       at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:53)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
       at org.jfrog.storage.wrapper.JFrogConnectionWrapper.invoke(JFrogConnectionWrapper.java:106)
       ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.rollback(Unknown Source)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:396)
       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
       ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: New finding! At the same time when artifactory logs (not all) were stating issue - firewall Checkpoint was reporting malicious calls (from our artifactory to db) being blocked. No customization, default checkpoint functionality.